# Tensorboard tf.summary.image strange image colors

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am loading a series of 128x128 uint8 color images to Tensorflow using:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], name='x-input')
```

I first check that the image I am loading is fine so I check it using Matplotlib (notice Matplotlib uses BGR colors so I fix it before displaying):

```
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

and I get the following image:

[image]

which is what I expect. I then load to Tensorboard with:

```
tf.summary.image('input', x, 1)
```

but the image show is:

[image]

Image is ok but the colors are all messed up. Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, it was CV2.imread that was causing the problem. CV2 reads BGR instead of RGB, so the images where loaded incorrectly and Tensorflow was showing them as it should.